# Как соxранить введенные значения после редактирования html() элемента посредством js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Динамически добавляю и удаляю блоки (наборы текстовых полей) на странице. После удаления непоследнего элемента нарушается их нумерация. Делаю пересчет нумерации скриптом. Но если я уже заполнил поля, то после выполнения скрипта они очищаются. Как сохранить значения проще всего. Каждое поле перед редактированием отдельно сохранять не очень хочется, т.к. там не только инпуты но и выпадающие списки , и их больше, чем представлено во фрагменте ниже...

```
    // Пересчет нумерации в элементарных блоках "по порядку"
function reCount(){
    count = 0;
    $("#all-prj-container .re-count").each(function() {
        count++;
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/projectname[0-9]{1,3}/g, "projectname" + count));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/subprojectname[0-9]{1,3}/g, "subprojectname" + count));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/reporttimeproject[0-9]{1,3}/g, "reporttimeproject" + count));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/textareareport[0-9]{1,3}/g, "textareareport" + count));
    });
}


    // Удаляем блок для записи проекта и обновляем слушатели
function myFunctionRemove() {
    blockToRemove = $(this).attr('data-parent-container');
    prjCounter = parseInt(projectscounter.value);
    if (prjCounter>1) {
        document.getElementById(blockToRemove).remove();
        for(i=0;i<buttonremove.length;i++){
            buttonremove[i].addEventListener('click', myFunctionRemove, false);
        }
        prjCounter -= 1;
        projectscounter.value = prjCounter;
        reCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: Одно уточнение... Айди текстовых полей могут меняться этим же скриптом. Например у поля был айдишник **projectname5**, а станет **projectname4**. Не знаю насколько это важно, но на всякий случай.

Comment: А что мешает перед удалением сохранить написанный текст в какой-нибудь массив? (У вас ведь блоки не по воле Божьей удаляются?) Или в `localStorage/cookie`, если есть необходимость.

Comment: Что представляет собой соответствующий html? Какую его часть Вы пытаетесь изменить?

Comment: Ну это ж с каждым полем нужно возиться, сохранять его в массив, затем восстанавливать из массива. А там еще и выпадающие списки. Я просто надеялся, что в js есть способ, который умеет это делать без вмешательства.
@Igor , этот html  - часть формы с полями. Такие части добавляются динамически. И здесь могут быть такие элементы 1) <select class="form-control" name="projectname1">.... или 2) <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reporttimeproject1" placeholder="" value="">

Comment: @ya.ymer Чтобы сохранить данные в массив (если нет получше способа выйти из положения) я должен каким-то образом сначала определить айди элемента. А я его не знаю. Это может быть projectname1, а может и projectname101. Тогда придется как-то в цикле по id находить по регулярке первый элемент, который подходит под /projectname[0-9]{1,3}/g, сохранять его значение, а затем возвращать по новому айдишнику после внесения изменений скриптом. Как-то через-чур...

Comment: я действительно не понимаю, похоже. что мешает из объекта события вытянуть таргет и получить value? покажите код, который отвечает за удаление этого вашего инпута.

Comment: @ya.ymer ,
            // Удаляем блок для записи проекта и обновляем слушатели
    function myFunctionRemove() {
        blockToRemove = $(this).attr('data-parent-container');
        prjCounter = parseInt(projectscounter.value);
        if (prjCounter>1) {
            document.getElementById(blockToRemove).remove();
            for(i=0;i<buttonremove.length;i++){
                buttonremove[i].addEventListener('click', myFunctionRemove, false);
            }
            prjCounter -= 1;
            projectscounter.value = prjCounter;
            reCount();
        }
    }

Comment: стоило бы добавить в сам вопрос, или хотя бы обернуть в markdown, как код. у вас же передаётся ид - `blockToRemove`, в чём проблема использовать его до удаления?

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем вам пересчитывать и менять id элементов?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko , я меняю для того, чтобы после отправки данных в форме сервер в цикле смог проверить их валидность и если они невалидны, то вернуть ошибки. В этом случае ошибка появится например под полем например **id="reporttimeproject55"**, а не под всеми полями  которых один и тот же айпишник. фреймаорк Laravel

Comment: @Stepan Kovalenko , задал отдельный вопрос на тему "Какой оптимальный способ организовать отправку и обработку динамически создаваемых полей на клиенте (Laravel)?"

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties#свойство-dataset-data-атрибуты